# Filter list with REST

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, query, odata

I'm trying to filter a lookup column on my list using rest
this is the column on my list
[image]

it's a look up (connected to another list)

and my rest on the list 
[image]
My query should get all the items that are equal to 4

also my column name in the list is _x05d0__x05d6__x05d5__x05e8_
and when I did the rest query the column name was _x05d0__x05d6__x05d5__x05e8_Id

*the column names aren't in english and yes I know that english is the best option when creating columns but it wasn't me, it's an old list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To filter lookup columns you have to use expand and filter properties.
First mention the property in select statement and expand then apply filter**

Use Ajax Get Request,

---

```
var select = "$select=normalCol1,lookUpCol/Title,lookUpCol/Id&";

var expand = "$expand=lookUpCol/Id&";

var filter = "$filter=lookUpCol/Id eq 4";

var url = _sppagecontextinfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(list title)/items?"+select+expand +filter ;***

$.ajax({
url:url,
type:"GET"
headers :{"Accept": "application/json;odata:verbose"}
}).then(successHandler,errorHandler)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!  I guees I missed something when I wrote the query.I dii it like you explained with select,expand and filter variables.

Answer (score 1):

Use this rest query

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(list title)/items?$expand=lookUpCol/Id&$filter=lookUpCol/Id eq 4
```

It should work.